# PHP Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a ten nodes proxmox cluster that is offering hosting for different websites that I develop. Some of these websites are using the divi theme and everything is working fine, but I'm continuing to receive a warning on only one of these in my apache2 log

```
PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /var/www/anekitalia/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/functions.php on line 1876
```

I searched the file and it reports this on that line

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_builder_enqueue_font' ) ) :
function et_builder_enqueue_font( $font_name ) {
global $et_fonts_queue, $et_user_fonts_queue;

$fonts = et_builder_get_fonts();
$websafe_fonts = et_builder_get_websafe_fonts();
$user_fonts = et_builder_get_custom_fonts();
$removed_fonts_mapping = et_builder_old_fonts_mapping();

/************************THE ABOVE LINE IS 1876**************************************/
      /***************************************************************/

if ( array_key_exists( $font_name, $user_fonts ) ) {
    $et_user_fonts_queue[ $font_name ] = $user_fonts[$font_name];
    return;
}

// Skip enqueueing if font name is not found. Possibly happen if support for particular font need to be dropped
if ( ! array_key_exists( $font_name, $fonts ) && ! isset( $removed_fonts_mapping[ $font_name ] ) ) {
    return;
}

// Skip enqueueing for websafe fonts
if ( array_key_exists( $font_name, $websafe_fonts ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( isset( $removed_fonts_mapping[ $font_name ] ) ){
    $font_name = $removed_fonts_mapping[ $font_name ]['parent_font'];
}
$font_character_set = $fonts[ $font_name ]['character_set'];

global $shortname;

// Force enabled subsets for existing sites once
if ( ! et_get_option( "{$shortname}_skip_font_subset_force", false ) ) {
    et_update_option( "{$shortname}_gf_enable_all_character_sets", 'on' );
    et_update_option( "{$shortname}_skip_font_subset_force", true );
}

// By default, only latin and latin-ext subsets are loaded, all available subsets can be enabled in ePanel
if ( 'false' === et_get_option( "{$shortname}_gf_enable_all_character_sets", 'false' ) ) {
    $latin_ext = '';

    if ( false !== strpos( $fonts[$font_name]['character_set'], 'latin-ext' ) ) {
        $latin_ext = ',latin-ext';
    }

    $font_character_set = "latin{$latin_ext}";
}

$font_name_slug = sprintf(
    'et-gf-%1$s',
    strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '-', $font_name ) )
);

$queued_font = array(
    'font' => sprintf( '%s:%s',
        str_replace( ' ', '+', $font_name ),
        apply_filters( 'et_builder_set_styles', $fonts[ $font_name ]['styles'], $font_name )
    ),
    'subset' => apply_filters( 'et_builder_set_character_set', $font_character_set, $font_name ),
);

// Enqueue google fonts
$et_fonts_queue[$font_name_slug] = $queued_font;
}
endif;
```

anyone with experience on divi theme? I have tried to disable every possible plugin for compatibility issue but problem still appears.
many thanks

Comment: so it is saying that one of the font variables is a boolean. do you know which one?

Comment: "THE ABOVE LINE IS 1876" makes me wonder, do you mean the error is thrown at `$removed_fonts_mapping = et_builder_old_fonts_mapping();`? If yes, we should see the code of this function because i see no `array_key_exists` there. Wouldn't the error rather be "below", here: `if ( array_key_exists( $font_name, $user_fonts ) ) {`?

Comment: `$user_font` is a boolean. It is set here: `$user_fonts = et_builder_get_custom_fonts();`. What is `et_builder_get_custom_fonts();` doing?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a function.php that is included in the theme, I really don't know how it works.. maybe this is related to some material icons that I have included but I deleted the googlapis stylesheet with no success

Comment: i don't know how this would be related to a stylesheet, but replacing the line by `if ( is_array($user_fonts) && array_key_exists( $font_name, $user_fonts ) ) {` should remove the warning

Comment: ^^ though, the next time you update your theme, the error will return if they have not fixed it.

Comment: I think that this is not a theme bug cause all other websites gives me a clear log, I think that someday I uploaded a custom font trough the divi builder interface(they have a tool that let me upload ttf fonts) and probably I have deleted the font during development but the site is very huge and the error is given on any page.. I don't know..

Comment: it can still be a theme bug that for whatever reason `et_builder_get_custom_fonts` returns `false` instead an empty array when custom fonts are added then you delete them all.. i don't know

Comment: no.. I just fixed this just uploading the font that I had deleted some days ago.. it was a really stupid question sorry for that but the the suggestions about "so it is saying that one of the font variables is a boolean. do you know which one? " gives me a starting point so I will check as answered many thanks

Comment: this shouldn't be happening - they have not made any error handling here. ergo this is a bug.

Comment: I agree that this could be an oversight on the developer's part. I do see that do have recent changes: [link]https://github.com/wp-premium-themes/Divi